# How to delete all folders in desktop using cmd/batch?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

If we want to delete all files in desktop we usually use,

```
del desktop\*.*
```

What if we want to delete all folders and subfolders in desktop ?

i tried,

```
rmdir desktop\*
```

doesn't works. Pls fix and help me. I tried searching other forums and google and i found this below code,

```
set folder="C:\test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b')
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't works with desktop. Pls help me to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
rmdir /s /q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\."
```